# Packages installation failed from 14 to 15 without errors

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

I'm using yarn 3.3.0 as package manager. What weird is new yarn only support `.yarnrc.yml` instead of `.yarnrc`. But angular still try to find the old one. But it's no help removing `.yarnrc`

```
❯ ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 --verbose --force
Locating potential npmrc files:
Trying 'C:\Users\setti\.npmrc'...found.
Locating potential yarnrc files:
Trying 'C:\Users\setti\.yarnrc'...found.
The installed Angular CLI version is outdated.
Installing a temporary Angular CLI versioned 15.0.0 to perform the update.
× Packages installation failed, see above.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `.npmrc` file in the root folder and try to enable legacy-peers during the update

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
strict-peer-dependencies=false
```

In npm the key is `legacy-peer-deps`, in pnpm `strict-peer-dependencies`. I don't know the name in yarm, maybe same as npm.

Ensure you run the ng update with the param `--allow-dirty --force --verbose`

Comment: It's ok after I update cli manually and run ng update again. IDK if this method useful. But I'll mark as answer for now.

Comment: I had the same problem and with this config the update continued